# SSIS Error - Load data into Fact Table - The system reports 80 percent memory load

Tags: ssis, buffer, etl, star-schema

I've the following package in order to load data from dimensions to Fact Table:

[image]

An when I execute this packages I getting the following error:

```
Error: The system reports 80 percent memory load. There are 25769267200 bytes of physical memory with 5078392832 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 5730304 bytes free. The paging file has 71665074176 bytes with 48505516032 bytes free.
```

It means that I need to add more capacity to my machine? Or modifying the package I will get results? I'm working in Windows Server 2012 64 bits...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sort and lookup transformations better alternative is to use a Stored procedure where you can sort or perform lookup. It will be much faster than the current implementation. Memory related issue will not occur.

Comment: many thanks! Which will be the goal of the Stored Procedure? Can I use it in SSIS?

Comment: Yes call your stored procedures using ExecuteSQLTask. In your stored procedure check whatever you are doing using Lookup. Source and destination in your package are OLEDB. It means even data that you are importing can be done inside stored procedure.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: DIM_1 I only compare with Fact Table if the Sugorrate_Key already exists. And in Agregatte I do an AVG on my two facts that comes from SA

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the Same issue and I just Resolved By Changing the Debugging as run64bit as True